# How to reuse a method from a different class

Tags: java, android, firebase, code-reuse

I have an authenticateID method which searches in the database to find a match and does something. I guess it will take long to explain so here is my code:

```
public boolean authenticateStudentID() {

    boolean success = true;

    final String studentID = etStudentID.getText().toString().trim();
    final String module = etModule.getText().toString().trim();
    final String degree = etDegree.getText().toString().trim();
    final String room = etRoom.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String fullname = etfullname.getText().toString().trim();
    final String loginID = etLoginID.getText().toString().trim();

    if (success) {
        databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { // wtf is this advanecd for loop
                    //map string string because our key is a string and value is a string, map has a key and value object
                    Map<String, String> map = (Map) snapshot.getValue();
                    if (map != null) { //if the values and keys are not null
                        String studentIDMatch = map.get("studentID");

                      //  Log.v("E_VALUE", "students ID entered : " + studentIDMatch);
                      //  Log.v("E_VALUE", "students ID from db: " + studentID);
                        if (studentID.equals(studentIDMatch)) {
                            String uniqueKey = databaseRef.push().getKey();

                            NewStudentAccounts sam = new NewStudentAccounts
                                    (studentID, loginID, email, fullname, module, degree, room);

                            databaseRef.child(uniqueKey).setValue(sam);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your account registration has been successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Student Credentials Entered!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
    return success;
```

I want to know how I can reuse this method for another class instead of copy and pasting code. Please guide me, I really appreciate it.

```
private void addNewStudent() {

    findViewById(R.id.buttonAddStudent).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            View addStudentActivityDialog = LayoutInflater.from(LecturerAccount.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_add_student,null);

            etStudentName = addStudentActivityDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentName);
            etStudentUserID = addStudentActivityDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentUserID);

            AlertDialog.Builder addStudentBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LecturerAccount.this);

            addStudentBuilder.setMessage("STAR").setView(addStudentActivityDialog).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String studentName = etStudentName.getText().toString();
                    String studentID = etStudentUserID.getText().toString();

                    registerActivity = new RegisterActivity(); //calling the instance of the class here

                    if (registerActivity.authenticateStudentID() == true){
                        studentarray.add(studentName);
                    }

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("cancel", null).setCancelable(false);
            AlertDialog newStudentDialog = addStudentBuilder.create();
            newStudentDialog.show();
        }
    });

}
```

My if statement here calling the function, I am totally clueless here.

Comment: the 'private' clause on your function is a big hint ;)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of changing it to public but if I use it in another class how can I call it the way I want it.

Comment: Then you really must add some code to your question, showing how you want to call it...There are a few ways

Comment: alright, I will try prepare some code and show my thinking.

Comment: I have added what I want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)` is an asynchronous callback event from `firebase` you must implement your own callback method to get notified of the result.

One approach would be to use interfaces.

create a separate class Auth

```
public class Auth {

public static void authenticateStudentID(final String studentID, final AuthListener listener) {

    DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("your reference");

    databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { // wtf is this advanecd for loop
                //map string string because our key is a string and value is a string, map has a key and value object
                Map<String, String> map = (Map) snapshot.getValue();
                if (map != null) { //if the values and keys are not null
                    String studentIDMatch = map.get("studentID");

                    if (studentID.equals(studentIDMatch)) {

                        if (listener != null)
                            listener.onAuthSuccess();


                    } else {

                        if (listener != null)
                            listener.onAuthFailure();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onAuthFailure();
        }
    });
}

public interface AuthListener {
    void onAuthSuccess();

    void onAuthFailure();
}
```

}

And then call it by

```
Auth.authenticateStudentID(studentId, new Auth.AuthListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthFailure() {

        }
    });
```

wherever required

Comment: thanks for that example, you changed its type from boolean to void. This breaks my code when I want to call the method if it returns true.

Answer (score 1):

As the method you want to reuse should be "public" first of all. It simply means that it can be publically accessed among other classes of that project. And after making it public you can simply refer it using the class name.

Here is an example of this :

```
Class2 instance = new Class2();
instance.publicMehtodToBeAcessedInThisClass(any parameters);
```

But in your case, you will have to copy and paste the code to another class file only.
Reason: Because you are fetching data from the layout file of your Java file and this will crash the app. Either you should further modularize your code and handle this by making a separate function for fetching all this data. Otherwise, copy pasting only a method from one class to another will not make your application run into any performance issue or lags.

Comment: ooo thanks a lot. Can you tell me more about how I can go about modularising my code.

Comment: Yes sure @Samir. Modularity is a property which makes your code more effective and readable. When making complex and large-scale applications especially in Android you should always try to modularize your code. Firstly identify important function in your code to be performed and then write a function for each of the important actions. This enables reusability of your code too. Well, the debate on modularity can go on and on. So I would strongly suggest you to google it and increase your knowledge regarding this as this will surely help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Access modifier is incorrect. Good old java doc will explain better than me:
[access modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

In order to access it, you have to create an instance like so:

```
YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
yourCLass.authenticateStudentID();
```

The YourClass is usually the name of the file where this code you pasted located in.

Comment: I don't know Java, but can you make a static call like YourClass.authenticateStudentID();?

Comment: I have done this, thanks but I want to check if the newly created ID is not in the database so that there is no duplicates

Comment: static is possible, but then you have to ensure that all calls in the method do not refer to a non-static field or method. Compiler will help you there

Comment: @Samir well your question is not related to the original question. you did not provide your attempt.

Comment: I could just copy and paste that authenticateStudentID body. But this is not what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shown, there are two issues you need to deal with:

1. As noted, having it `private` doesn't do you much good when it comes to reuse.
2. It looks like the `databaseRef` object is a class property. So you'll need to pass this in, rather than rely on the class property for that class, since you want to use it from another class. (Or you can put this method, and the `databaseRef` property, in a superclass and have your two classes inherit from it.)

In general - think about what your method needs to *do*, and then what it *needs* to do that. Those should shape how you make the method more usable from other parts of your code.